# link_to same action, different conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a recipe model with a has_many through association (category, categorisation).

On the homepage I am listing all the categories and I would like to create a `link_to` on each one that links to a page with all the recipes belonging to that category.

What would it be the best approach?

I can crete a different action for each category on the recipe controller with some condition `Recipe.where(category: "something")` but this will require also a different view.

Is there a better way (with a better RESTful approach) to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to do this is to use [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to give you a way to specify the "parent" model (in your case `Category`):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
   resources :recipes, only :index
end

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @category = Category.find params[:category_id] if params[:category_id]
       @recipes  = @category ? @category.recipes : Recipe.all
   end
end
```

The above will allow you to link to the following:

```
#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <%= link_to "Recipes", [category, :recipes] %>
<% end %>
```

This will alow you to populate the `recipes#index` action with the following:

```
#app/views/recipes/index.html.erb
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
   <%= recipe.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich. Problem is a recipe could have different categories, would your advise still apply? Also why only index? Many thanks again!

Comment: Only `index` because that's what you asked in the question :). When you mention "different categories", can you give context? Scoping the `recipe` around a `category` (as above) is independent of any categories. This means if your `recipe` is in `CatA` && `CatB`, it will be accessible in both categories

Comment: Right, fair enough! :) The recipe controller has a complete "CRUD" at the moment as well as some checkboxes on the view to select on which category is on. e.g.  A salad can be under sides and healthy food.

Comment: You can include whatever you like in the controller. I often write large answers, but in this case, I felt it appropriate to keep it succinct. I figured you were intelligent/experienced enough to add your own twists onto what I was saying, which seems to be the case :)

Answer (score 2):

Use nested resources for this:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :recipes
end
```

This will produce routes like `/categories/:category_id/recipes`, which will be an `index` action for recipes, but have category id in params

Also you can use a slug for categories instead of number ids.